# Rails 4 - javascript runtime required in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, asset-pipeline

I just updated a Rails 3.2.x app to 4.0.2.
When I deployed to production (ubuntu, MRI 2.0) I got the good old error about the lack of a javascript runtime.

I quickly fixed it by installing **node**, but it makes me wonder.

I prefer to precompile the assets locally, check them into git, and then push them to the production server along with the rest of the application.

With Rails 3.2 this system has always allowed me to not care about a js runtime in production, as the application doesn't need to compile coffeescript or run uglyfier.

So, the question is: what has changed with Rails 4? Is there a config option to control this behaviour?
I checked my (rails 4) config file, and I think that the production evironment is already configured to NOT fallback to live compilation.

---

### assets-related config options:

**config/application.rb**

```
config.assets.precompile += ['html5shim.js']
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

**config/environments/production.rb**

```
# Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
config.serve_static_assets = false

# Compress JavaScripts and CSS
config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier
# config.assets.css_compressor = :sass

# Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
config.assets.compile = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true

# Version of your assets, change this if you want to expire all your assets
config.assets.version = '1.0'
```

Comment: could you post your production.rb so we can see the configuration. Did you specify any overriding definitions in environment.rb?

Comment: done. Could it be because of `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier`?

Comment: also: no, nothing fancy in environment.rb

Comment: the guides recommend to set `config.assets.compress = true` in production, but this doesn't help with your question.  
Can you just try commenting the `js_compressor`-line in production? Sorry, i can't reproduce this too easily.

Comment: I'm afraid that `config.assets.compress = true` is the old Rails 3 config statement, replaced by `config.assets.js_compressor = :uglifier` in Rails 4

Comment: Interesting, so there is something not completely correct in the rails guides. [configuring assets](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#configuring-assets) and [environments in production.rb](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#config-environments-production-rb) still list the value, but in [sprockets rails](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#sprockets-rails) it is recommended to be changed.

Comment: Not sure about the 'configuring assets' guide, but the second url you linked is relative to upgrading from Rails 3.0 to 3.1 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case someone hit this question as I did. I had the same problem and this link pointed me to the right direction: https://mattbrictson.com/upgrading-to-rails-4-with-capistrano. Specifically the following statement: *In Rails 4, the standard Gemfile no longer has an :assets group, which means asset pipeline gems are always loaded in production, on all servers*. I precompile my assets locally and upload them to production, so there is no reason to have JS runtime on production server.

In my case I added group `:asset` to my `Gemfile` putting there asset-related gems. In my case it was:

```
group :asset do
  gem 'uglifier'
  gem 'execjs'
end
```

My capistrano tasks on production install bundle without `:asset` group, so after this change JS runtime is no longer required on production.